# Fixing TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Tags: for-loop, numpy-ndarray

[trying to print a loop over x for values of q, but keep getting this syntax error. Can anyone help with this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s1dr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a vector/array, not a single value. You may try the following:

```py
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(f'x = {x} -> q = {q}')
```

You could also take a look at [numpy.array2string](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) function.